# Magento 2: How to override mini-cart default template html file?

Tags: magento2, overrides

How to override 
`/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html` file in our custom theme?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

first we have to override web/template files to our magento theme file,
in my case content.html

```
Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

After changes in `content.html` file, we have to deploy static file using command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

OR

You have to delete content.html(i have to change content in this file) file from `pub/static/frontend/Magento/buytea/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart` and reload page again.

Changes are applied.

Comment: Trying to override homepage. But not working

Comment: which page, please give me path

Comment: I have below folder structure

`magento2
 |_ app
   |_ design
   |_ frontend
  |_ Magento
   |_luma
     |_Magento_Theme
       |_templates
      |_root.phtml
    composer.json
    registration.php
    theme.xml` & refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138223/how-to-override-html-file-in-magento-2-1/

Comment: you have to defined your custom theme, inside luma its not working, if you want to changes inside luma theme then go to your vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma

Comment: I would like to override Luma Theme Cannot do that?

Comment: you have to create your custom theme and set luma theme as parent. you directly not defined luma theme as defined you in above query

Comment: Is there any guide or link you can provide it will be really helpful. Because i exactly don't know how to do it

Comment: you can refer this post for override luma theme, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136289/how-to-add-banner-or-slider-in-magento-2-1-1-home-page-and-how-to-create-custom/136292#136292

Comment: I tried running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` after creating the new file in my custom theme, but it never showed my changes. After manually deleting the file in pub/static it then showed up

Answer (score 17):

There is another way. **We should know that we can override the html template via RequireJS. We don't need to create a custom theme**. In your custom module, create a `requirejs-config.js`:

*app/code/{Vendor}/{Module_Name}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html':
                'Vendor_ModuleName/template/minicart/content.html'
        }
    }
};
```

A more explain we can read more [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108788/how-to-override-template-files-for-magento2-extension/121702#121702).

Comment: hey. when i override `content.html` this way then why its give me blank? minicart.

Comment: There is this file `Vendor_ModuleName/template/minicart/content.html` in `pub/static`?

Comment: yes.. and also my config code in `requirejs-config.js` is availbale

Comment: when i see console, its also taking my file instead of core. but don't know why its display nothing.

Comment: Tried to clear your Browser Cache?

Comment: cleared, run with new browser but no luck.

Comment: ohhh its give me error `getCartParam is not defined`. you have any solution?

Comment: Which is your Magento version? 2.1.x?

Comment: i am working with Magento 2.0.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48707/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-chirag).

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, this was very useful. Followed this approach to override OOB content.html in custom module for Magento 2.2.6 minicart and it's been working fine.

Answer (score 7):

You can override this by adding this folder to your theme:

```
Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart
```

In this folder you can create the content.html file. After a change made in this file make sure you flush your browser cache to see the changes.

Comment: i have try same you suggest this but not works.

Comment: Did you deploy static files? And cleared cache?

Comment: yes, its working fine after clear static files and it will auto generate new file on next page load.

Answer (score 1):

Although Khoa TruongDinh's answer was really helpful, there are some details missing so here is a full example:

Working minicart example, copy the html template to:

```
[theme_path]/Magento_Theme/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

and in themes requirejs-config.js =>

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html': 'Magento_Theme/template/minicart/content.html'
        }
    }
};
```

See also core bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5832

Answer (score -1):

Open file for modifying minicart contents:

```
/app/design/frontend/your_theme/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

Open file for modifying minicart product contents :

```
/app/design/frontend/Eglo/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

After modification, You have to deploy the theme using `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`then it will show.

If modification is not populated then modify tempaltes in below directory for showing runtime changes:

```
/pub/static/frontend/Your_theme/Theme/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart
```

Comment: you shouldn't modify stuff in pub/static.. it will be overridden by static deploy command anyway...