# Getting the product SKU in the header mini-cart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, knockoutjs

I want to be able to display the product `SKU` in the mini-cart of a Magento 2 site. But I'm not sure how to use `KnockoutJS` to pull in additional product information. The template that is being called is here:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

And contains code like:

```
<strong class="product-item-name">
    <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</strong>
```

So my direct question would be: where are the values for the product set and how can I change them around to add or remove product details?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, the header minicart will get the data from customer data

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js**

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'sidebar'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko) {
    'use strict';
    ......
    this.cart = customerData.get('cart');
    ......
}
```

Look into the customer data js `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js`, we can get the customer data from local storage. For example, in your browser console, run the line: `localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')`, we also can get the cart information.
[image]

```
{
  "cart": {
    "summary_count": 1,
    ....
    "items": [
      {
      ......   
        "qty": 1,
        "item_id": "11728",
        "configure_url": "http://magento2-demo/checkout/cart/configure/id/11728/product_id/1817/",
        "is_visible_in_site_visibility": true,
        "product_name": "Breathe-Easy Tank",
        "product_url": "http://magento2-demo/breathe-easy-tank.html",
        "product_has_url": true,
        "canApplyMsrp": false
      }
    ],
    .......
  }
}
```

Navigate to 
**vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php**

```
protected function doGetItemData()
    {
       .......
        return [
            'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
            'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
            'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
            'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
            'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_name' => $this->item->getProduct()->getName(),
            'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
            'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
           .....
    }
```

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/AbstractItem.php**

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getItemData(Item $item)
{
    $this->item = $item;
    return \array_merge(
        ['product_type' => $item->getProductType()],
        $this->doGetItemData()
    );
}
```

To get the SKU item, I think we need to add data to `getItemData()` (Should try [with Plugin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134357/33057)). And then [override the template html](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96540/magento-2-how-to-override-mini-cart-default-template-html-file/121713#121713) `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

```
 <div class="product-item-details">

                    <!-- ko text: product_sku --><!-- /ko -->
```

### Update Magento 2.1.0 version

In the Magento 2.1.0, you only need to override `default.html`. This is because the method `doGetItemData` has already the product sku.

Comment: Thank you! Filled in a ton of the 'hows' on this question!

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh  thanks for the great answer. This works perfect. Can you please tell me how we can do this same in in the checkout summary section. I have found a lot but cant get a location where to add the  new attribute instead of name in checkout summary .

Comment: Be careful, if you have configurable products, you need to override this class also : `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\CustomerData\ConfigurableItem` and for grouped product : `Magento\GroupedProduct\CustomerData\GroupedItem`

Comment: @FranckGarnier I have just checked seem that we don't need to override these classes. Only add `!-- ko text: product_sku --><!-- /ko -->`, the sku will show for configurable product. My Magento version is 2.1.5.

Comment: Right for product_sku, but if you need add extra information not natively present, careful about these classes, try to use plugins instead.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh how do I get sku in magento 2.1? i tried using <!-- ko text: product_sku --><!-- /ko --> but it didnt give me anything. please help

Comment: @Joey try to clear Browser Cache or use Incognito mode.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh tried that. I even cleared magento cache. not working. what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, very good explanation from @Khoa TruongDinh about the flow of getting item in minicart template.

> how can I change them around to add or remove product details?

I found a way how you can extend minicart template with custom attributes of the product. 
To do that first you need to override **vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php** with [DI Preferences](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#abstraction-implementation-mappings)

Create **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml** ot override DefaultItem object

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="Vendor\Module\Preferences\MiniCartItem" />
</config>
```

Then create new object to override doGetItemData() method and add **custom_attribute** with key **product_custom_attribute**

File: **app/code/Vendor/Module/Preferences/MiniCartItem.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Preferences;

class MiniCartItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $msrpHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $configurationPool,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $helper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel
    ) {
        $this->configurationPool = $configurationPool;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->msrpHelper = $msrpHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->checkoutHelper = $checkoutHelper;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->productModel = $productModel;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
        $product = $this->productModel->load($this->item->getProduct()->getId());
        return [
            'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
            'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
            'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
            'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
            'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_name' => $this->item->getProduct()->getName(),
            'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
            'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
            'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
            'product_image' => [
                'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
                'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
                'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
                'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
            ],
            'product_custom_attribute' => $this->helper->productAttribute($product, $product->getCustomAttribute(), 'custom_attribute'),
            'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
                && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
        ];
    }
}
```

Notice that I am injecting

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel

to the construct method because I need to load full product data to access my custom_attribute. If there is a better way please tell me.

And finally you can display the new attribute in

> view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html:

```
 <div class="product-item-details">

                    <!-- ko text: product_custom_attribute --><!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Using `'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku()` does work to pull in the sku, so while i don't need the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel` to grab that, i will use it to grab some other product info. I finally got the preference up and running, so your method does work like a charm!

Comment: For custom attributes you need `$productModel` to load the product with all attributes and then retrieve them with `$this->helper`. If it's working you can upvote my answer.

Comment: I did, and they only let me vote once. If i could mark your answer as correct as well as Khoa's i would. I'll post around and see if we can get more votes for you, as i have yet to see any one answer this problem anywhere else and this one knocks it out the park.