# Magento2 get product options and price object in custom javscript

Tags: magento2, custom-options, quantity, product-page

How can i get the product custom options and price object in my custom javascript.

I would like to modify the product price on quantity change and also  need to update the price of custom options based on the quantity.

Comment: We can get the product custom options from local storage: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123879/getting-the-product-sku-in-the-header-mini-cart/123903?noredirect=1#comment167902_123903

Comment: There is no product custom options in local storage.

Comment: If we add product to cart successfully, we can get product options from cart. Seem your question isn't clear, you want to get product options in case? Please, update your question.