# Magento 2 Mini Cart Plugin di.xml doesn't pass attribute information

Tags: magento2, quote, mini-cart, knockoutjs, quoteitem

I have a issue that i need to output a product attribute that isn't option in Mini Cart.

Here is my plugin scructure:

Vendor/Checkout/etc/di.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Checkout::Add_Color_Attribute" type="Vendor\Checkout\Plugin\AddAttribute" disabled="false" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Vendor/Checkout/etc/module.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Checkout" setup_version="0.0.1" data_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Vendor/Checkout/Plugin/AddAttribute/AddAttribute.php

```
namespace Vendor\Checkout\Plugin;

class AddAttribute
{
    protected function afterGetItemData($subject, $proceed, $item)
    {
        $result = $proceed($item);

        $result['color'] = $this->$item->getProduct()
            ->load($this->$item->getId())
            ->getAttributeText('color');

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Template

Vendor/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

```
    <div class="product-item-details">

        <!-- ko if: options.length -->
        <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
            <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                <ol class="product options list">
                    <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                    <li>
                        <span class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></span>:
                        <span class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: color.length -->
                    <li>
                        <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Color'"></span>:
                        <span class="values">
                            <span data-bind="html: color"></span>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-pricing">
            <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

            <div class="details-map">
                <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
            <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <div class="product actions">
            <div class="secondary">
                <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                   class="action delete">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot get color attribute passed to quote.

In result i get this error http://prntscr.com/ct1a9r

Looks like color attribute isn't passed to quote item.

Comment: Try this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134338/i-want-to-customize-my-minicart-in-magento-2-i-need-to-add-3-attributes/134357#134357

Comment: @AaronAllen Tried with no results :/ Try passing pure text attributes as text didn't work.

Comment: @AaronAllen http://prntscr.com/ct2h7z not working ;/

Comment: I noticed in your code you have an 'after' plugin that should be an 'around'. Also the ko bind should be `item.color`, not `color`.

Comment: @AaronAllen http://prntscr.com/ct2r0d http://prnt.sc/ct2rth with no results

Comment: And the template?

Comment: @AaronAllen http://pastebin.com/ZTrE6Ekv

Comment: Magento version 2.1.1

Comment: My only guess is that the plugin isn't running for some reason. Try running `magento setup:upgrade` then `magento cache:flush`.

Comment: @AaronAllen Also didn't work. :(

Comment: Anyone found the solution? I'm stuck with this aswell