# Magento2, echo product attribute in minicart

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, mini-cart

How can I access product attribute to echo it in minicart    `/web/template/minicart/item/default.html` Like below works for cart page `templates/cart/item/default.phtml`

```
<?php
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$product_id = $product->getId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
?>
```

...

```
echo $_product->getData('myattr')
```

Comment: Which value are print using above echo ?

Comment: The code I mentioned above is what I used in default.phtml for cart page, I need same but in html file as for minicart is /item/default.html.

Comment: The answe to my question was in below link [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134338/i-want-to-customize-my-minicart-in-magento-2-i-need-to-add-3-attributes](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134338/i-want-to-customize-my-minicart-in-magento-2-i-need-to-add-3-attributes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134338/i-want-to-customize-my-minicart-in-magento-2-i-need-to-add-3-attributes)

DefaultItem.php

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Plugin;


use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

class DefaultItem
{

    protected $productRepo;

    public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepo = $productRepository;
    }

    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, \Closure $proceed, Item $item)
    {
        $data = $proceed($item);

        /** @var Product $product */
        $product = $this->productRepo->getById($item->getProduct()->getId());
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();

        $atts = [
            "product_manufacturer" => $attributes['manufacturer']->getFrontend()->getValue($product),
            "product_part_number" => $attributes['part_number']->getFrontend()->getValue($product)
        ];

        return array_merge($data, $atts);
    }
}
```

And add below in `default.html` to echo custom attributes:

```
...
<div data-bind="html: 'SKU#: ' + item.product_sku"></div>
<div data-bind="html: 'Manufacturer: ' + item.product_manufacturer"></div>
<div data-bind="html: 'Part #: ' + item.product_part_number"></div>
....
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/80357)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, I completed the answer, but I don't get why down vote point here!

Comment: well I'm not the one who downvoted the answer so I don't know. Sometimes people downvote but don't give any reason

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, the link was the solution indeed, how to keep this answer up!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

`$_attributeValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`

For your case you need to create plugin for `\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem::getItemData` and extend data.

```
public function getItemData(Item $item)
{
    $this->item = $item;
    return \array_merge(
        ['product_type' => $item->getProductType()],
        ['product_attribute' => $attributeValue]
        $this->doGetItemData()
    );
}
```

After that in template `web/template/minicart/item/default.html` new data will be accessible

```
 <strong class="product-item-name">
            <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
            <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <label data-bind="text: product_attribute"></label>
        </strong>
```

refer [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1688) link for which file you have to override or [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/487f5f45/app/code/Magento/Checkout/CustomerData/AbstractItem.php#L24-L31) link for where you have to add product attribute value.

May be it will work.

Comment: no. You can pass this value using js and get in html.
    window.ProductConfig = {
        'Attrvalue': '<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($status); ?>'
    }

Comment: Where to place the js? Can you edit your answer with required steps. Thanks

Comment: for your case you need to create plugin for \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem::getItemData and extend data.
After that in template web/template/minicart/item/default.html new data will be accessible

Comment: I'm almost there, do you know how can I make condition in the html file. Like if product_attribute == "mytext" then display it?

Comment: `<!-- ko if: product_attribute --> <!-- ko -->` if not work then write condition `\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem::getItemData` to pass value or empty

Comment: @Zinat, You can set condition for knockout as, <!-- ko if: product_attribute == "My Text"--><!-- /ko -->

Comment: where you add default.html? add path.

Answer (score 0):

In html, we can apply condition like below code:

> ```
>  <if args="product_attribute == 'mytext'">
>     here is your content like div 
> </if>
> ```

Its Magento 2 code not knockout js, its working  fine for apply conditions.