# Minicart -product_sku in Magento 2

Tags: javascript, magento2.2, knockoutjs, php-7

Below file contains product_sku value.

```
view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html file.
```

how to get/use product_sku in custom js file .If anyone knows please explain me

Answer (score 0):

Please try with create new custom module : 
This is the module directory:

```
|   registration.php
|   
+---etc
|   |   module.xml
|   |   catalog_attributes.xml
|   |   
|   \---frontend
|           di.xml
|           
+---Plugin
|       DefaultItem.php
|       
\---view
    +---frontend
    |   \---layout
    |           checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml
    |           
    \---web
        \---template
            \---mini cart
                \---item
                        default.html
```

**catalog_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="manufacturer"/>
        <attribute name="part_number"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem">
        <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Your\Module\Plugin\DefaultItem" disabled="false" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**DefaultItem.php**

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

class DefaultItem
{
    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, \Closure $proceed, Item $item)
    {
        $data = $proceed($item);
        $product = $item->getProduct();

        $atts = [
            "product_manufacturer" => $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'),
            "product_part_number" => $product->getAttributeText('product_part_number')
        ];

        return array_merge($data, $atts);
    }
}
```

SKU already exists in data so no need to add it.

checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Your_Module/minicart/item/default</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

`default.html` is a copy of `Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html` with changes made at line 66

```
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: 
                  product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div data-bind="html: 'SKU#: ' + item.product_sku"></div>
                <div data-bind="html: 'Manufacturer: ' + item.product_manufacturer"></div>
                <div data-bind="html: 'Part #: ' + item.product_part_number"></div>

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty"
                           maxlength="12"/>
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

using for this : [I want to customize my minicart in Magento 2. I need to add 3 attributes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134338/i-want-to-customize-my-minicart-in-magento-2-i-need-to-add-3-attributes)