# Magento 2 : Minicart customization - add 2 attribute in minicart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I followed this link for minicart customization but i did not work for me href "[I want to customize my minicart in Magento 2. I need to add 3 attributes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134338/i-want-to-customize-my-minicart-in-magento-2-i-need-to-add-3-attributes)  "

I followed above link but my minicart not working as before follow above link... i just want to add sku and product id into the minicart.

```
<?php
namespace Matech\Minicart\Plugin; //use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

class DefaultItem
{
    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, \Closure $proceed, Item $item)
    {
        $data = $proceed($item);
        $product = $item->getProduct();

        $atts = [
            'product_id' => $product->getAttributeText('product_id'),
            'product_sku' => $product->getAttributeText('sku')
        ];

        return array_merge($data, $atts);
    }
}


default.html
<!-- wahaj -->
<div data-bind="html: 'SKU#: ' + item.product_sku"></div>
<div data-bind="html: 'id: ' + item.product_id"></div>

<!-- wahaj -->
<!-- <div data-bind="html: 'SKU#: ' + item.product_sku"></div>
<div data-bind="html: 'Manufacturer: ' + item.product_manufacturer"></div>
<div data-bind="html: 'Part #: ' + item.product_part_number"></div> -->
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: ok wait a minute

Comment: <?php

namespace Matech\Minicart\Plugin;

//use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

class DefaultItem
{
    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, \Closure $proceed, Item $item)
    {
        $data = $proceed($item);
        $product = $item->getProduct();

        $atts = [
            "product_id" => $product->getAttributeText('product_id'),
            "product_sku" => $product->getAttributeText('sku')
        ];

        return array_merge($data, $atts);
    }
}

Comment: default.html  <!-- wahaj -->
   <div data-bind="html: 'SKU#: ' + item.product_sku"></div>
                <div data-bind="html: 'id: ' + item.product_id"></div>
   <!--  wahaj -->
    
    <!-- 
    
    <div data-bind="html: 'SKU#: ' + item.product_sku"></div>
                <div data-bind="html: 'Manufacturer: ' + item.product_manufacturer"></div>
                <div data-bind="html: 'Part #: ' + item.product_part_number"></div>
    -->

Comment: Please update this in question itself

Comment: done it in my question please check it out