# Minicart not show the custom attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have custom attribute and its "**global**" and product listing "yes" i want to add this attribute in minicart this attribute show in product view page but not show in minicart . basically i checked it by using debug minicart not load the custom attribute because its not show in inspect element (network section) help me please my question is how i get attribute without reload the product

Comment: Already answered here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134338/i-want-to-customize-my-minicart-in-magento-2-i-need-to-add-3-attributes

Comment: here is not my answer please read it again !!!

Comment: You want a custom product attribute to show in the minicart , correct?

Comment: yes , please help me

Comment: well then read that article that i shared. It answers your question