# Update Mini Cart count Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart, section

I want to update minicart count. I was found some code regarding mini cart on `sections.xml` but it works with products not for item count on toplink with cart item.

Now you can see below code what I'm getting regarding the mini cart.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
      <action name="modulename/controler/addProduct">
          <section name="cart"/>
      </action>
   </config>
```

Can you please suggest how can I implement update cart item qty on toplink?

Answer (score 0):

Your session file should be under `etc/frontend` folder: `app/code/Vendor/MiniCart/etc/frontend/sections.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="{frontName}/{ActionPath}/{ActionName}">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

We also need to know the item count on mini cart gets the data from local storage: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/123903/33057

Comment: i have update cart using programatically and i am not using any JS regarding the functionality.

Comment: `update cart using programatically`  you updated the cart by using controller?

Comment: yes using controller

Comment: Can you update your question with full code lines?