# Magento 2 pop-up authentication not showing

Tags: magento2, popup, guest-checkout, modal-popup

I'm using Magento 2.1.8, and I disable Magento guest checkout like this:

[image: example configuration]

after saving the configuration, I cleared Magento cache. The problem occur when I tried to click the checkout button at minicart, it didn't redirect me to any page or show pop-up authentication. The button just does nothing when clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your Browser Local Storage. AFAIK, some configuration is stored on local storage (including Allow guest checkout config).

[image]

Comment: i've deleted all local storage and session storage but it's still not working

Comment: Seem that you're using multi stores?

Comment: no i'm not using multistore

Comment: Did you try to get the local storage: `localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')`? Read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/123903/33057

Comment: yeah i got this `isGuestCheckoutAllowed":false`