# How to add banner or slider in magento 2.1.1 home page and how to create custom theme?

Tags: magento-2.1.1

Please explain both question in detail:

**How to add slider in home page.**
I want to keep homepage banner slider, so please suggest for banner slider in magento 2.

**How to create custom theme in magento.**
How to create custom theme in magento 2, give me list of files and step to create theme.

Answer (score 0):

**Homepage Banner Slider:**
Find Banner slider from magento marketplace from link here [Marketplace site](https://marketplace.magento.com/),

**Theme create:**

You can get reference from magento docs, [Create Magento theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

Theme structure for magento 2:

```
app/design/frontend/
├── <Vendorname>/
│   │   ├── <themename>/  
│   │   │   ├── ...web
│   │   │   │   ├── ...css
│   │   │   │   ├── ...images
│   │   │   │   ├── ...js
│   │   │   ├── registration.php
│   │   │   ├── theme.xml
```

You have to just create theme inside folder `app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename`

You have to get files from core theme blank or luma and set your parent theme inside your theme file.

You have to copy files and folder from `magento2/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma` or `magento2/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank` based on your parent theme.

Required files is,
**registration.php** file,

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Vendor/themename',
    __DIR__
);
```

**theme.xml**

keep below code,

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Custom Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

> Get web folder from parent theme to your current theme.

After Getting required files and folder,
Run command through cmd,

First run command for deployment,

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Remove var folder from root.

Now you have to set theme from Magento admin panel.

Go To admin panel left side menu,

> Content -> Design -> Configuration

**Click on Your main website store link and set your theme from here.**

Comment: It's not showing in Content -> Design -> Configuration Dropdown

Comment: please let me know your magneto version, above version is realted to magento2.1.*

Comment: Yes it's Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0

Comment: When u run static-content:deploy command. It should display my new theme which as parent as Luma theme or not? Because it's not displaying currently

Comment: you have to set theme from content -> design -> configuration

Comment: My theme is not displaying over there in Admin

Comment: Have you checked your entry are generated in theme table or not in database?