# Magento 2 : Override Template From "module-theme"

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I want to override sections.phtml file from `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/templates/html/`

I am using default magento theme

I have created structure,

`app/design/frontend/Magento/Magento-Theme/templates/html/sections.phtml`

But it is not running, the default one is getting loaded.

Comment: you have to just create theme in your project and after setup theme you can override directly same as above. you can refer from http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136289/how-to-add-banner-or-slider-in-magento-2-1-1-home-page-and-how-to-create-custom

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this two ways, choose either one as per your requirements [from module or theme]

**From Theme**

Create one custom theme after that you need to create the below file for override sections.phtml

> app/design/frontend/YourVendorName/YourThemeName/Magento-Theme/templates/html/sections.phtml

**From Module**

Create custom module after that create below default.xml file to overwrite sections.phtml

`app/code/YourVendorName/YourModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">YourVendorName_YourModuleName::sections.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

place the **sections.phtml** in below path

> app/code/YourVendorName/YourModuleName/view/frontend/templates/sections.phtml

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if You create Your new theme and inherit from base

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

copy from here

`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/templates/html/sections.phtml`

add in your theme
`/app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/sections.phtml`

Comment: +1 from me, but if I am not using any theme, I am using default magento 2 theme, then what should be strutcture

Comment: /app/design/frontend/Magento/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/sections.phtml   Try this ;)

Comment: okay.. let me check that

Comment: no still not working

Comment: are You using luma theme ?  /app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/templates‌​/html/sections.phtml

Comment: yes @Martins I am using luma

Comment: is "then" also to be included ?

Comment: @DishaSingh eddied above. Doses this worked out ?

Comment: No @Martins it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head for half an hour on this...

The [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html) suggests that the templates location should be:

```
<theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/templates/<path_to_templates>
```

The template we are after being in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/templates/html/` you would think that the path should be

```
<theme_dir>/magento_module-theme/templates/<path_to_templates>
```

which would correspond to `<Namespace>` underscore `<Module>` as per the folder structure, but that's not what the documentation means.

Open the module `registration.php` and see how it is registered: `Magento_Theme` so namespace here is `Magento` and module name is `Theme` and that's it.

So in the end your path will be:

```
<theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/templates/<path_to_templates>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong path in the structure you have to use a theme from default magento like `Magento_Blank` or create a new theme that has inheritance from a magento theme ( check devdocs on how to create new theme ) and your file has to be in the following structure `design/frontend/[Your_Package]/[Your_theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/sections.phtml`