# Magento 2: How to override Luma Theme Home Page

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides, custom, design

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0 on WAMP Windows 10

I already referred

[Magento 2: How to override mini-cart default template html file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96540/magento-2-how-to-override-mini-cart-default-template-html-file/)

Would like to override Magento 2 Default Luma Theme

I have below folder structure

```
magento2
 |_ app
   |_ design
      |_ frontend
        |_ Custom
            |_Theme
              |_Magento_Theme
                |_templates
                  |_root.phtml     - Copy of Luma
                registration.php
                theme.xml
```

**app\design\frontend\Custom\Theme\Magento_Theme\registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Custom/Theme',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app\design\frontend\Custom\Theme\Magento_Theme\theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>My Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

I run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` & clear cache as well. It's not displaying my newly created Theme in `Admin -> Content -> Design -> Configuration`. Edit Dropdown List.

What I'm still missing?

Comment: This is also will be helpful http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**When creating any new theme or module you need to define registration.php file at root of your module or theme folder.**

> Always use theme name in lowercase, Because Magento used this standard
>   for theme name declaration.

You haven't any problem for keep Theme name in camelcase but use standard way is much appreciated.

You have to define registration.php file inside Magento_Theme folder, its in wrong place.

Correct diagram of theme structure will be below,

```
magento2
 |_ app
   |_ design
      |_ frontend
        |_ Custom
            |_theme
              |_Magento_Theme
                |_templates
                  |_root.phtml     - Copy of Luma
              |_registration.php
              |_theme.xml
```

Your path for registration.php is `app\design\frontend\Custom\theme\registration.php`

*registration.php* file :

```
<?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
      'frontend/Custom/theme',
      __DIR__
);
```

your theme.xml file path will be,

```
app\design\frontend\Custom\theme\theme.xml
```

*theme.xml* file :

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>Custom Theme</title>
   <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
   <media>
      <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
   </media>
</theme>
```

After all setup is completed, don't forget to run deploy command for the theme,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Check inside your admin panel, `Content -> Design -> Configuration` for set your custom theme.

Remove cache and check in the frontend.

Comment: Bijal Usean & SH Patel. Accepting Answer of @Rakesh because previously I'm in discussion with him on this issue.

Comment: It's giving error while saving from Admin `Cannot read contents from file "D:/wamp/www/magento2/" Warning!file_get_contents(D:/wamp/www/magento2/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. So unable to save  & Enable New Theme

Comment: please run upgrade command, then run deploy command, remove var folder from root and check

Comment: Nope. Still Issue

Comment: Follow up here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138381/magento-2-new-them-saving-issue-on-admin-wamp

Comment: if still face unable to see the changes on frontend then ?

Answer (score 1):

you place **theme.xml** and **registration.php** in wrong place, the actual location is

`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/registration.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/<vendor>/<theme>',
    __DIR__
);
```

`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/theme.xml`

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Vendor Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

**note:** place preview.jpg in `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/media/preview.jpg`

these two files enough to getting your theme list in Admin, then apply your theme.

If you would like to override luma templates for example `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`, you can make the changes of that template in `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

Comment: It's giving error while saving from Admin `Cannot read contents from file "D:/wamp/www/magento2/" Warning!file_get_contents(D:/wamp/www/magento2/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.` So unable to save & Enable New Theme

Comment: it seems like file permission issues, have you check do you set right permission as per magento standard.

Comment: As mentioned in question `I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0 on WAMP Windows 10`

Comment: Follow up here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138381/magento-2-new-them-saving-issue-on-admin-wamp

Comment: please check your magento root directory  access user and their user group, it should be the web server user and their group, as well as check read/write permission of that directory. refer this two link you can get more idea http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html   http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/91870/36463

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect path you have used.

Follow bellow instruction for creating new custom theme.

Create **theme.xml** file in 
`/app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/theme.xml` with below code.

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Custom Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

Create registration.php file in `app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/registration.php` with below code.

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Custom/theme',
    __DIR__
);
```

copy preview.jpg from

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/media/preview.jpg
```

add to

```
app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/media/preview.jpg
```

Now you can see your custom theme in admin, select custom theme from admin and save it.

Comment: It's giving error while saving from Admin `Cannot read contents from file "D:/wamp/www/magento2/" Warning!file_get_contents(D:/wamp/www/magento2/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.` So unable to save & Enable New Theme

Comment: Luma theme save work properly ?

Comment: Follow up here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138381/magento-2-new-them-saving-issue-on-admin-wamp

Answer (score 1):

The magic your looking for is taught @ https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/create-a-custom-child-theme-from-luma-theme/

in short what's missing from all answers is copy files _theme.less and _extends.less from magento-theme-luma/web/css/source/ directory to your custom theme directory/web/css/source.

Refer to: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html for specifics on what and how to extend/override