# Magento 2: New theme saving issue on Admin WAMP

Tags: magento2, admin, theme, permissions

In continue with [Magento 2: How to override Luma Theme Home Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138345/magento-2-how-to-override-luma-theme-home-page)

I'm getting error

> Cannot read contents from file "D:/wamp/www/magento2/"
>   Warning!file_get_contents(D:/wamp/www/magento2/): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory

[image]

As i'm using **Magento 2 CE on WAMP Windows 10**, it shouldn't be file permission issue.

Comment: Have you checked your entry inside databse tablename with theme? in your theme table contains entry for all themes,

Comment: Yes in `theme` table it added my New Theme. Checked

Comment: Have you checked with theme table entry for your theme have field type with value 0?

Comment: Yes it has 0 value like all

Comment: if you switch theme to luma its working? and all other pages are working fine?

Comment: How to Switch Theme??

Comment: go to database find core_config_data table search design/theme/theme_id from path field, you have seen two entry remove scope with store entry and check again after remove root var folder

Comment: There is only 1 entry @Rakesh with scope: default, scope_id:0, value:2 which is for Luma not Mine theme, Because i'm not able to change from Admin

Comment: if you find one entry means your custom theme is not applied. have you checked your log file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46014/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-rakesh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have missing web and etc folder in your theme folder.

please add below code in your theme,

you need to copy entire **web** folder from 
**/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma to app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web** folder

Also need to copy **etc folder** from default luma theme to your **Vendor/Theme folder and check again**

web folder is neccessary to add inside theme.

Now run command **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

run deployment command, **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Remove var folder and clear browser cache.

Set Your custom theme from

> Content -> Design -> Configuration

Comment: Surely it shouldn't be necessary to copy the Luma theme folder? Should be sufficient to *inherit* from Luma theme. I can't quote you chapter and verse at the moment, but I though theme inheritance was one of the advertised features.

Comment: where is stored etc folder and where need to place