# How to edit custom css In Magento 2 and we using porto theme

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, css

How to **edit custom css In Magento** 2 and we using **porto theme** ?

I'm using this code base theme working

```
app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name
```

run below command to set developer mode

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

and **clear cache and deploy static-content**

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

**But porto theme not working**

Comment: I am also using same theme, but its working for me. Where do you get the problem?

Comment: app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less  this link we change the css but not have problem not change in css

Comment: and also we try to this link to change the css but not working app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/web/css/source/_module.less

Comment: Create custom module to change the css. Below link will help you to change the css. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108785/45181

Comment: ok we try it.. but in theme css any change in the style it not working ?

Answer (score 2):

We are using Same Porto Theme.

**I recommend do not make changes in Porto Theme. Because they are upgrading their Versions. Once you upgrade to their latest version, your changes will be given.**

So create your theme, by setting Porto as Parent.

```
magento\app\design\frontend\My\ThemeName\web\css\source\header.less
magento\app\design\frontend\My\ThemeName\web\css\source\footer.less
```

For how to create theme

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

[Magento 2: How to override Luma Theme Home Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138345/magento-2-how-to-override-luma-theme-home-page)

**magento\app\design\frontend\My\theme_name\theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>My Porto Child</title>
    <parent>Smartwave/porto</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

At the End Run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to static-content:deploy content if you are in developer mode. Just clear the following directories and you'll be fine to go. Note: first website call will be slow: `$ rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/*`. NEVER forget the `*`, otherwise the important `.htaccess` gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To override LUMA consider as parent theme  you need to change `theme.xml` file in folllowing location :

```
app\design\frontend\vendor_name\theme_name\theme.xml
```

using below code

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>Your Theme name</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/luma</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```