# Overide files in Luma theme

Tags: magento2, php, cms

I want to overide files located  in

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.php
```

**but the old file is being called from vendor folder**, maybe above structure is wrong?

Comment: The file should be named 'header.phtml' rather than 'header.php'

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/138358

Comment: You need to create first a `luma_child` theme to not update the natif one `Magento_Luma` then you place your new file in : `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma_child/templates/header.phtml`

Comment: I would recommend against using the `Magento` vendor namespace in the app design folder, it's better to use your own namespace. There might be a time and place for it, but better to have it follow the magento standards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom theme that inherits from Luma to be able to override the file correctly. Create the needed files:

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme_name}/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme_name}',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme_name}/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Your Custom Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

And then place your override here:

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme_name}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.php

You then need to set your theme in the admin under `Content -> Theme -> Configurations`

Once the site is using your theme you will have the file override correctly. Note that you will have to replace all the default luma static blocks that are on the home page and category pages, the widgets that place them there are locked to the theme and will vanish when you switch this.

I also did a deeper write up on this: https://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-2-theming-basics/