# Magento 2: add a custom phtml side bar to the homepage

Tags: magento2.3.3

i want to add a custom side bar phtml file in the home page that would show specific categories. i couldn't find a specific layout or template file for the homepage. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer my question:
first, the homepage like many other pages(ex: footer) are CMS pages, meaning that they are created and used by the admin, meaning that they don't have a particular layout or template or block files.
1-if you want to change the layout to **2-columns-left** for example, you can either do it the admin panel or like I did edit the row in the database with **installData**:

```
$setup->startSetup();
$setup->updateTableRow('cms_page', 'page_id', '2', 'page_layout', '2columns-left');
$setup->endSetup();
```

2- next you want to create your sidebar **template** and it's the corresponding **block** in your custom module.
3- finally in your custom theme in

*vendore/theme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml*

add this:

```
 <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">

            <referenceContainer name="columns">
                <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" before="main">
                    <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main">
                        <block class="vendore\module\Block\SideBar"
                               template="vendore_module::side_menu.phtml"/>
                    </container>
                </container>
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

and like this you can a custom side bar in your home page

Answer (score 0):

[Magento 2: How to override Luma Theme Home Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138345/magento-2-how-to-override-luma-theme-home-page)

here you can find the details hope this helps if helps accept as answer

Comment: did not help at all