# Magento 2 - How to override knockoutjs template?

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, knockoutjs

I try to override the following template from my own module

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html
```

but I don't find the file where I can override it, I searched the whole `module-checkout` folder for the place where the `default.hmtl` is added, but can't find it.

Is it possible to override the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for `minicart/item` and now I found:

**vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml**

I override it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/minicart/item/default</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override this by adding this folder to your theme:

```
Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart
```

In this folder you can create the default.html file. After a change made in this file make sure you flush your browser cache to see the changes.

OR

After changes in default.html file, we have to deploy static file using command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Reference : [Magento 2: How to override mini-cart default template html file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96540/magento-2-how-to-override-mini-cart-default-template-html-file)

Comment: I tried to figure out how to override it in my module though, not theme. And whats the content.html file? Do you mean default.phtml?

Comment: @Black, yes "default.html"

Answer (score 1):

cretae requirejs-config.js

```
Copy default.html vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html

past app/code/Vendor/Module/view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html":
                "Vendor_Module/template/minicart/item/default.html"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: override checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml

Comment: Thats a duplicate of my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @author Moazzam ALi
 * Created by PhpStorm
 * User: moazzam
 * Date: 30/7/22
 * Time: 12:27 AM
 */
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "Taxjar_SalesTax/template/suggested_address_template.html":
                "Vendor_Module/template/suggested_address_template.html"
        }
    }
};
```